# show swirling arrow around the text view frame

Tags: java, android

How do you make an animation that revolves around the text. The text must remain constant, it will just turn around the edge. There is an object rotating in the direction of the arrow

[image: etc image]

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is clockwise animation for Textview.

[1]. Design XML as below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="40dp"
            android:text="Hello Rotate Me!"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvRotation"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_txt"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="start"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

[2]. Create **anim** named folder in **res** directory. In **anim** create file named **clockwise.xml** and put below code into it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

[3]. put below code into your activity

```
TextView edtRotation=findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID);
Animation aniRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.clockwise);
edtRotation.startAnimation(aniRotate);
```

[4]. Background Drawable as per you want but my drawable file code is **back_txt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="#0000ff" android:width="2dp"/>

</shape>
```